# Trigger YouTube video by button click - AMP

Tags: amp-html

I currently have an `amp-youtube` element that looks like the following

```
  <amp-youtube 
    id="youtubevideo" 
    data-videoid="xxxxxxxx" 
    layout="responsive" loop 
    width="480" 
    height="270">
  </amp-youtube>
```

Is there any way to trigger this video through another button? It looks like I can only get the video to play is if I click on the actual video with my cursor.

Is it possible to trigger it to play by clicking on a separate button?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the ID of the YouTube element, in your case `youtubevideo`, and assign the `play` action to it once a button is pressed, like this:

```
<button on="tap:youtubevideo.play">
    Play YouTube Video
</button>
```

Comment: @prawn happy to help